# D3jS show info on hover over circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mouseover

I have a line graph that adds circles on the line for each data point. On hover, I would like to display the "Date" and "Close" of the data point.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwm0bkgz/)

Here is what I've tried:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        svg.transition()        
            .duration(100)      
            .style("opacity", 1);       
        svg .html(d.date + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        svg.transition()        
            .duration(100)      
            .style("opacity", 1);   
    })
```

Something *is* happening with the code but it is very slow and doesnt show the "Date" and "Close" on mouseover.

How can I make the "Date" and "Close" show/hide for each data point circle when hovered over?

Comment: `svg` is your SVG selection. You probably want to create a `<div>` for the tooltip, so use the adequate selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it will be to include d3.tip for your solution.
I use d3.tip.v0.6.3.js.

what you'll have to do first is to create the tool tip view in a var:

```js
var toolTip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<div style='margin-bottom: -12px; color:"+d.data.color+"'>"+d.name+"</div></br><div style='margin-bottom: -5px'>"+ d.data.label+"</div></br>";
    });
```

The 'function(d)' after the '.html' returns html piece for the tooltip, just don't forget the inverted commas.

right after that function you should add:

```js
svg.call(toolTip);
```

that way your svg will know this tooltip var you created, you can create this var right after you svg.

last part will be to connect this tooltip to 2 events on the d3 elements: mouseover&mouseout:

```js
.on("mouseover", toolTip.show )
.on("mouseout", toolTip.hide);
```

Hope it will help